# Sitefinity 4 Set Theme Name Programmatically

Tags: sitefinity-4

In SiteFinity 4, Can we set Theme Name in Page Load of Master Page which is used as Page Template?

Best Wishes,
Aki

Answer (score 0):

Page themes need to be set in the Page_PreInit event in asp.net

Unfortunately, Master Pages do not have the Page_PreInit event, and this is where you need to set the theme.

This is a limitation of master pages themselves, not Sitefinity.

However it is possible to set a theme at runtime by creating a custom route handler to intercept the request and modify the theme on the fly.

first create a custom route class:

```
public class CustomRouteHandler : PageRouteHandler
{
    protected override void SetPageDirectives(Page handler, IPageData pageData)
    {
        base.SetPageDirectives(handler, pageData);

        var url = HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl.ToLower();
        var themeName = "AlternativeTheme"; 
        if (url.StartsWith("/alternative"))
            ThemeController.SetPageTheme(themeName, handler);

    }

    public static void RegisterType()
    {
        ObjectFactory.Container.RegisterType<PageRouteHandler, CustomRouteHandler>();
    }
}
```

Then you need to register that route in the Global.asax file:

```
public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Telerik.Sitefinity.Services.SystemManager.ApplicationStart += SystemManager_ApplicationStart;
    }

    void SystemManager_ApplicationStart(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CustomRouteHandler.RegisterType();
    }
}
```

Now each request will go through that handler, and you can modify the theme based on any custom condition you need.

I'm planning to put together a blog post and video that goes into more detail on how this is done and what you can do with it, but this is the basic idea of how it works.

I hope this is helpful!

Comment: To which assemblies do the following types belong:
1. PageRouteHandler (either MS or Telerik, neither have the overriden method SetPageDirectives)
2. Page
3. IPageData (Telerik.Sitefinity.Pages.Model)?

Thanks

Comment: it appears that method is now obsolete, I believe the correct method to override is BuildHttpHandler

I hope this is helpful, please let me know if this doesn't work!